# XML validation error

Tags: xml, validation

I'm trying to validate the following XML but I'm unable to, can you please spot the error?

```
<!-- menu: its a menu -->
<menu id="Welcome">
    <!--audio: file to play -->
    <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\Welcome.vox" />
</menu>

<!-- form: its a menu -->
<menu id="LanguageSelection">
    <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\LanguageSelection.vox" />

    <input timeout="5" max_timeout="2" max_invalid_input="2" valid_dtmfs="1, 2">

        <!-- noinput: if timeout occurred, execute this -->
        <noinput>
            <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\Timeout.vox" />
        </noinput>

        <!-- nomatch: if wrong dtmf given, following will execute -->
        <nomatch>
            <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\InvalidInput.vox" />
        </nomatch>

        <switch>
            <dtmf-1>
                <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\EnglishSelected.vox" />
            </dtmf-1>

            <dtmf-2>
                <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\UrduSelected.vox" />
            </dtmf-2>
        </switch>
    </input>
</menu>

<menu id="MainMenu">
    <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\MainMenu.vox" />

    <input timeout="5" max_timeout="2" max_invalid_input="2" valid_dtmfs="1, 2">

        <!-- noinput: if timeout occurred, execute this -->
        <noinput>
            <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\Timeout.vox" />
        </noinput>

        <!-- nomatch: if wrong dtmf given, following will execute -->
        <nomatch>
            <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\InvalidInput.vox"/>
        </nomatch>

        <switch>
            <dtmf-1>
                <goto menu="InformationMenu" />
            </dtmf-1>

            <dtmf-2>
                <goto menu="SupportMenu" />
            </dtmf-2>
        </switch>
    </input>
</menu>
```

I get the following error while validating with [Validome.org](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/).

Error:  *The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.*

Error Position: <**m**enu id="LanguageSelection">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than one top level element `<menu>`.

Try the following. I have added `<MenuItems>` as a top level element and closed it at the end.

```
<MenuItems>
<!-- menu: its a menu -->
<menu id="Welcome">
    <!--audio: file to play -->
    <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\Welcome.vox" />
</menu>

<!-- form: its a menu -->
<menu id="LanguageSelection">
    <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\LanguageSelection.vox" />

    <input timeout="5" max_timeout="2" max_invalid_input="2" valid_dtmfs="1, 2">

        <!-- noinput: if timeout occurred, execute this -->
        <noinput>
                <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\Timeout.vox" />
        </noinput>

        <!-- nomatch: if wrong dtmf given, following will execute -->
        <nomatch>
                <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\InvalidInput.vox" />
        </nomatch>

        <switch>
                <dtmf-1>
                        <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\EnglishSelected.vox" />
                </dtmf-1>

                <dtmf-2>
                        <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\UrduSelected.vox" />
                </dtmf-2>
        </switch>
    </input>
</menu>

<menu id="MainMenu">
    <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\MainMenu.vox" />

    <input timeout="5" max_timeout="2" max_invalid_input="2" valid_dtmfs="1, 2">

        <!-- noinput: if timeout occurred, execute this -->
        <noinput>
                <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\Timeout.vox" />
        </noinput>

        <!-- nomatch: if wrong dtmf given, following will execute -->
        <nomatch>
                <audio src="D:\Telephony\VOXs\InvalidInput.vox"/>
        </nomatch>

        <switch>
                <dtmf-1>
                        <goto menu="InformationMenu" />
                </dtmf-1>

                <dtmf-2>
                        <goto menu="SupportMenu" />
                </dtmf-2>
        </switch>
    </input>
</menu>
</MenuItems>
```

You can check ur xml quickly by opening it in ie. When I opened your xml this is what I got.

```
Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document. Error processing resource 'file://Users/shoban/...

<menu id="LanguageSelection">
-^
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a root level element. For example, wrap the menu elements inside of a `<menus>` tag.

```
<menus>
    <menu>
    </menu>
    <menu>
    </menu>
</menus>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Well-formedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling)

> SUMMARY:
>
> The XML specification defines an XML
>   document as a text which is
>   well-formed, i.e., it satisfies a list
>   of syntax rules provided in the
>   specification. The list is fairly
>   lengthy; some key points are:
>
> 1. It contains only properly-encoded
>      legal Unicode characters.
> 2. None of the special syntax
>      characters such as "<" and "&"
>      appear except when performing their
>      markup-delineation roles.
> 3. The begin, end, and empty-element
>      tags which delimit the elements are
>      correctly nested, with none missing
>      and none overlapping.
> 4. The element tags are case-sensitive;
>      the beginning and end tags must
>      match exactly.
> 5. There is a single "root" element
>      which contains all the other
>      elements.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your issue is that your xml document has more than one root element per file.

In your particular case the basic structure of your document was:

```
<menu></menu>
<menu></menu>
<menu></menu>
```

That is defining 3 root elements in your document.

In order to define a single element you need to surround the three elements with a single root element as follows:

```
<menus>
   <menu></menu>
   <menu></menu>
   <menu></menu>
</menus>
```

You can find out more at this [simple tutorial I found](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmldocument.php).